# Webpack dev server start using production.webpack.config.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I  want to start my webpack deb server using my `production.webpack.config.js` file . please anyone help me

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --inline --hot",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production node_modules/.bin/webpack -p --progress --colors"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guys i find my answer and I think this answer help everyone to work multiple configuration file in webpack . in your package.json file add this line

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js --progress --inline --hot",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production node_modules/.bin/webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js --progress --colors"
  },
```

then problem solved

Comment: That's literally what I said 30 minutes ago, but good job finding it on your own at least.